# Geonode installation issue

Tags: server, apt

I use Ubuntu Server 16.04 on VirtualBox. I was installing Geonode according to [its documentation](http://docs.geonode.org/en/master/tutorials/install_and_admin/quick_install.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:geonode/stable
sudo apt-get update
```

but I have this error:

```
E: some index files failed to download. they have been ignored or old ones used instead
```

I can't get the full output because I use VirtualBox but I took a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please [edit] you question and  the full output of `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: I upload a screenshot of the output @heemayl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 404 error messages are saying that there is no installation candidate for Ubuntu 16.04. However, I went to check the Geonode PPA in Launchpad and saw that there is an installation candidate for Ubuntu 14.04. Therefore, I suggest you either ask the devs at Geonode's GitHub repo (https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode) to release packages for Ubuntu 16.04 or use Ubuntu 14.04.

If you don't want to see the 404 error messages (they don't harm your system, but they may be annoying), you can remove the offending PPA using one of the many ways given at [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists).

Comment: @MostafaShouman Yup I think just running 14.04 and then installing Geonode on it is the easiest way. Meanwhile, you can ask the devs if they have plans to support Ubuntu 16.04.